# Is encapsulate a private field into a variable a good practice? C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

For example:

```
public class Test
{
    private string _s;

    public Test()
    {
        var s = "hello";
        _s = s;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var s = _s;
        //  Use s for some reason.
    }

}
```

Should I use _s directly for my needs or store _s into another variable that point to it? What if there were a property instead of the private field?

Comment: What is gained by doing this?  It's not clear to me why you'd be creating variables that you already have.

Comment: only for a clean naming. but I ask this question to understand if I was right or not!

Comment: `"only for a clean naming"` - Name the class-level member `s` and the problem becomes moot.  If existing code needs to be improved, then improve the existing code.  Don't write more code to obfuscate the code you want to fix, just fix it.

Comment: Since you don't present a clear problem this question is opinion based as depending on scenario both cases (to copy value or to use it *directly*) are useful. E.g. multithreading.

Comment: In current state question feels like "why would you assign one variable to another in the code" - which is way too broad and non-specific. It is very rare you'd write code without such assignments.

Comment: do not I have to name a private field in a different way from the local variable?

Comment: @David, naming of `private` fields is a slim subject, I would disagree with your or [microsoft's](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,46) styling ;) To me underscore is fine since then I am able to use name in constructor or other method while following name convention and without `this`.

Comment: @CRK indeed you can name local variable same as field - did you tried?

Comment: @Sinatr: I often use an underscore as well.  It's a matter of personal preference.  That's not really the point I'm making.  The OP indicated that the reason he's doing this is to have "clean naming", for which I would recommend using a "clean name" in the first place.  However one personally defines a "clean name" is up to that person's preference.  But if the variable name is in some way *wrong*, then why create a new variable when you can just fix the existing one?

Answer (score 2):

First, "encapsulate" is not at all the word for what you're doing. You're talking about making a copy. In programming, to "encapsulate" means to hide the field and make everybody access it via code of some kind. In C# that almost always means a property (which is really just method calls disguised by syntactic sugar). In other languages it might be explicit get and set methods.

So. Should you make a copy?

Yes:

```
private int _from = 9;

public void f(int to)
{
    for (int i = _from; i < to; ++i)
    {
         //  stuff
    }
}
```

No:

```
public f2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("from is {0}", _from);
}
```

If you're going to be changing the value as you use it, but you don't want the private field to be changed, make a local copy and change that.

But beware: Value types such as `int` behave very, very differently than mutable reference types such as `SqlConnection` (see below).

If you won't be changing it, don't waste your time. In fact, if the field is a reference type and you create a local reference to it, somebody maintaining your code ages hence may mistake it for a local object and wrongly assume that changes to it won't have class-wide effects.

```
private SqlConnection _conn = null;

public MyClass()
{
     _conn = new SqlConnection();
}

public void f3()
{
    var c = _conn;

    // 150 lines of stuff

    //  OK, I guess we're done with it now!
    c.Dispose();
    c = null;

    //  Now _conn is not null, yet the next call to f3() will find it unexpectedly 
    //  in an invalid state. You really don't want that. 
}
```

Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: Don't know where I get this idea. Maybe on my own, maybe I thought that the code was more clean in this way but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to proxy the private field with a local variable. Most of the time, that field will be of a reference type (i.e., more or less, a class), so using a local variable only means one more reference to that object.

It could actually be harmful (anyway, doing unintended things) if you did that with a value-type field (an `int`, for example). You would act on the local variable, which is fine as long as you read it; but on write the field would not be changed.